# Application works on Heroku but no longer works locally?

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra

Ok so,
I have been working on a small webapp in sinatra. After taking the weekend off I am running into a strange problem and having trouble tracking it down.

My app so hosted on Heroku and works just fine there. However, now the app no longer works locally. Even cloning the source back from Heroku produces the same problem.

```
== Sinatra/1.3.2 has taken the stage on 4567 for development with backup from Thin
>> Thin web server (v1.3.1 codename Triple Espresso)
>> Maximum connections set to 1024
>> Listening on 0.0.0.0:4567, CTRL+C to stop
!! Unexpected error while processing request: undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass
```

I have tried to get this running again on three different computers (intel macmini, thunderbolt MacBook pro, & G4 mini) all produce the same error.

I have gone over my code looking for any unclosed or incomplete code & cannot find anything. Even reverting to a known working version with git produces the same error.

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated as my knowledge of ruby is still rather limited. If some one is interested/willing to take a look at my code I would be willing to share.

The only thing that may have changed: I updated gems on my development machine have been updated. But I don't see how that could effect the situation on the other two machines.

Comment: try git grep "<<" to see if you introduced this line somewhere.

Comment: also you might check if the newer rack versions changed anything. You might want to revert to 1.3 in your Gemfile.

Comment: That was the issue. I did not notice that rack was amoungst the updated. Thank you for your input.

Comment: there are more regressions in Rack 1.4. Quite annoying but great you could fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here's a discussion](https://github.com/Zapotek/arachni/issues/124) of the same error with Sinatra on a different app. A fix was discussed and one identified workaround was to roll back the Rack version from 1.4.0 to 1.3.6.

Comment: Fantastic! That was exactly the issue. Thank you so much!